# Django: Middleware making more entries

Tags: python, django, middleware

```
class Middleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        #ipreq(self)
        ip = request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
        make_entry(ip)

    def make_entry(self, ip):
        p = Logging_protocol.objects.create(proto = ip)

        p.save()
```

this is the code in my middleware class. the issue is its making two entries in table when logging in and also on logging out. I want to record IP once when the user logs inn. It also makes entry when the page is loaded from particular IP

Comment: Do you have a browser debugger/inspector running that is making two requests?

Comment: my code is hosted at a server. when i access it to login usign my browser and check my database table i found that its making two entries

Comment: Firstly I recommend to make sure that your view function does not run for a second time with a single request. If you use a debug version of Django app. server you could output some info (print "test") and look to a command line.

Comment: Even if you code is on a server, a double-request from your browser's tools can result in two requests. Also, please show your logging setup - do you have TWO logging handlers enabled?

Comment: and one more thing i wanted it to work it on very first request that is when the user logs inn but its putting IP on every page the user accesses. when user logs inn and he click or goes to 6 pages it enters 6 IP's but i wanted it to work only when user logged inn

Comment: i dont have two logging handlers enabled..

Comment: Following @stevejalim comment, you can also double check your plugins. For instance, W3C validator plugins can get your page's source with a second request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that middleware operates on every request. Accordingly, the code you should will record every request, not just logins/logouts.

You might like to look at the events framework to respond only to logins and logouts.

In addition, you should probably use new-style classes.

Comment: so there are some middlewares available that check whether or not the the request is coming from mobile or PC browser. So if anyone is using mobile so why it has to check for every request that the request is coming from mobile infact it should store in some session var that this for if request is coming for this session its form mobile. because user will be browsing through mobile. what do u say

Comment: @syedsabir Sure, but then you have to use sessions. Not everyone does. It is also more error prone.